# Control to display float array (f.e. Waveformdata, FFT-data etc)

Tags: c#, wpf, floating-point, controls, draw

I'm processing audio and I'd like to display several stages in my processing loop.

So I have for example some float arrays representing waveforms, FFT-data, PowerSpectrum-data, and some other stuff. All float[].

I'd like to display these float[] buffers using a single control that should probably have only a y-axis scale property.

Does anybody know if something like that is available somewhere for WPF ?
I'm not looking for complete charting libraries, I'd like to have something as simple as possible that does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the WPF WriteableBitmapEx project http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ which allows you quick ways of drawing over an image.